# Unable to ssh into IBM Flex Node

Tags: ssh, ibm

I have an IBM Flex node that I'm unable to ssh into (but am able to ssh from it into other machines).

When I tried to ssh in using SSH Secure Shell, I get the error message:
`Server responded "Algorithm negotiation failed". Key exchange with the remote host failed. This can happen for example if the remote host computer does not support the selected algorithms`.

When I tried to ssh in from another IBM server in the same chassis, I get the error after typing the password: `The user name or password you typed is not valid. You must login with the correct user name or password. If you do not know the correct password, ask your system administrator to reset your password on the chassis management module.` I'm pretty sure I typed in the correct password. And why would the CMM be involved with the SSH authentication on a server?

Comment: Solving ssh issues like this almost always requires looking at the server's logs.

Comment: Where can I find the server's logs?